# Exception при добавлении QGraphicsItem на сцену?

Tags: qt5, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsview

Класс `ball`:

```
ball.h:
#ifndef BALL_H
#define BALL_H
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <iostream>


class ball
{
public:
    ball(int x, int y,int R);
    void setPos(int newX, int newY);
    void setSpeed(int newSpeed);
    QPoint getPos();
    int getSpeed();
    QGraphicsEllipseItem* getBall();
private:
    int x;
    int y;
    int R;
    int speed;
    QGraphicsItem* ballObj;
};


#endif // BALL_H

ball.cpp:
#include "ball.h"

ball::ball(int x, int y,int R)
{
    this->x=x+10;
    this->y=y;
    this->R=R;
    ballObj = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(x,y,R,R);

}
void ball::setPos(int newX, int newY)
{
    this->x=newX;
    this->y=newY;
}
void ball::setSpeed(int newSpeed)
{
    this->speed=newSpeed;
}
QGraphicsEllipseItem* ball::getBall()
{
    return  this->ballObj;
}
QPoint ball::getPos()
{
    return QPoint(this->x,this->y);
}
int ball::getSpeed()
{
    return  this->speed;
}
```

Создание объекта:

```
ballObj=new ball(0,this->height(),10);

    gameBoard->scene()->addItem( ballObj->getBall());
```

Конструктор GameBoard:

```
GameBoard::GameBoard(QWidget *parent)
{
    gameBoard = new QGraphicsView();
    mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    gameBoard->setParent(parent);
    gameBoard->setMinimumSize(parent->width(),parent->height());
    gameBoard->setMouseTracking(true);
    gameBoard->grabMouse();

    boardPen.setColor(Qt::black);

    boardlBrush.setStyle(Qt::SolidPattern);
    scene=new QGraphicsScene();

    scene->addEllipse(0, 0, boardlWidth,boardHeigh, boardPen, boardlBrush);
    ballObj=new ball(0,this->height(),10);

    gameBoard->scene()->addItem( ballObj->getBall()); // Строка 20
    gameBoard->setScene(scene); // 21
}
```

Консруктор - отрабатывает нормально - смотрел под отладчиком:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- скриншот следующего шага после срабатывания точки останова

, но при попытке добавить на сцену  -получаю SegmentationFault - см скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Где вы создаете и добавляете объект сцены во вью?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, https://pastebin.com/yFZTYxh5

Полный проект:

https://github.com/BadCatsss/GraphicsViewDemo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

файл gameboard.cpp, конструктор, строки 20 и 21 должны быть поменяны местами, потому что вы вначале добавляете итем в несуществующую сцену у вью, а потому уже добавляете сцену во вью:

```
gameBoard->setScene(scene);
gameBoard->scene()->addItem( ballObj->getBall());
```

Либо так:

```
scene->addItem( ballObj->getBall() );
gameBoard->setScene(scene);
```